# call javascript api within apex controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, api, controller

I am using the GoogleMaps JS Api and I'm looking to cleanse addresses.  Is it possible for me to call this via a controller or do I need to do it within the browser?

I can use this to pass parameters but I'm unsure how to do that server-side (nor client side for that matter):

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start#ReverseGeocoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do so. [This GitHub repo](https://github.com/Internet-Creations/Creating-a-Geolocation-Trigger-in-Salesforce-Winter--13) gives an example of doing so. Here's a snapshot of the code at the time of this answer:

```
public class LocationCallouts {

     @future (callout=true)  // future method needed to run callouts from Triggers
      static public void getLocation(id accountId){
        // gather account info
        Account a = [SELECT BillingCity,BillingCountry,BillingPostalCode,BillingState,BillingStreet FROM Account WHERE id =: accountId];

        // create an address string
        String address = '';
        if (a.BillingStreet != null)
            address += a.BillingStreet +', ';
        if (a.BillingCity != null)
            address += a.BillingCity +', ';
        if (a.BillingState != null)
            address += a.BillingState +' ';
        if (a.BillingPostalCode != null)
            address += a.BillingPostalCode +', ';
        if (a.BillingCountry != null)
            address += a.BillingCountry;

        address = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(address, 'UTF-8');

        // build callout
        Http h = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+address+'&sensor=false');
        req.setMethod('GET');
        req.setTimeout(60000);

        try{  
            // callout
            HttpResponse res = h.send(req);

            // parse coordinates from response
            JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(res.getBody());
            double lat = null;
            double lon = null;
            while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
                if ((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) && 
                    (parser.getText() == 'location')){
                       parser.nextToken(); // object start
                       while (parser.nextToken() != JSONToken.END_OBJECT){
                           String txt = parser.getText();
                           parser.nextToken();
                           if (txt == 'lat')
                               lat = parser.getDoubleValue();
                           else if (txt == 'lng')
                               lon = parser.getDoubleValue();
                       }

                }
            }

            // update coordinates if we get back 
            if (lat != null){
                a.Location__Latitude__s = lat;
                a.Location__Longitude__s = lon;
                update a;        
            }    

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }   
    }
}
```

Note: This is not my code, but is simple enough that you should be able to use it almost verbatim. In a controller, you won't need a future method as long as you remember to use it *before* using a DML statement.

Credit goes to [the author](https://github.com/Internet-Creations) of the code.

Comment: very nice!  I'm trying to do the inverse right now Geo to address and I'm trying to figure out the parsing logic.

Comment: @tjcinnamon Just take the JSON example in the docs, head to [json2apex](http://json2apex.herokuapp.com/), generate your class from the JSON, then you can parse it using the provided method.